# Why this code does not work in the database?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Why this code does not work in the database?

```
public $sql;
public $data;

public function get() {
$this->sql .= 'SELECT users.name
     , users.username 
     , user_avatar_image 
  FROM users_information
  JOIN users
    ON users.id = users_information.user_id
 WHERE user_id = :user_id';


$this->data  = ["user_id" => 1273];

$result = $this->pdo->prepare($this->sql);
$result->execute($this->data);
$result = $result->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
return $result;
}
```

result =

> Warning:  PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter
>   number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in
>   ...

Comment: You're not showing enough code. We at least need the prepare and execute lines too. Use real code if possible too, what you've provided isn't valid PHP at the moment.

Comment: please share complete code, u have an issue with no of columns

Comment: you have a placeholder `:user_id` which is not resolvable. You should prepare the statement and bind a php variable to `:user_id`

Comment: Can you update your question title to make it more meaningful for others?

Comment: This code will not work at all because it has syntax errors, provide __real code__ that is not working and not parts.

Comment: everyone want to help but OP ......................

Comment: thank you , edit...

Comment: You seem to be concatenating to `$this->sql`. Can you echo `$this->sql` right before you prepare it, and show us the results?

Comment: Yes - very suspicious to use `$this->sql .= 'SELECT...` instead of `$this->sql = 'SELECT...`.  It could easily contain a value from a prior call.

Comment: Thank you ... Yes, the problem was from here $this->sql .=